# How to build fat libclang

Tags: cmake, clang

I am able to build llvm and clang on my OSX following this tutorial:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html
I use cmake with ninja for this.

then I can find my libclang.3.6.dylib under
`<path_to_llvm>/build/lib/libclang.3.6.dylib`. The problem is that library is not **fat**. I mean that it built for **x86_64** only. I can verify this with:
`lipo -info libclang.3.6.dylib`

This produces:
`Non-fat file: lib/libclang.3.6.dylib is architecture: x86_64`

But I also need **i386**

I have a few questions:

- How to build fat (x86_64 + i386) libclang.dylib and libclang.a ?
- Is it possible to build just these libraries without rebuilding whole llvm, clang, tools etc (whole build takes a few hours on my machine) ?

Answer (score 0):

Additional argument to cmake "-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64;i386" did the trick. I guess this works only for OSX.

Now if I run **lipo**, I will receive desired output.
`lipo -info lib/libclang.3.6.dylib
Architectures in the fat file: lib/libclang.3.6.dylib are: x86_64 i386`

But I still have to recompile whole llvm/clang project (takes a few hours)